# How to compute the limit of the following integral?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Given $b > 0$, let $g(x)$ be a continuous function defined on $[-b, b$]. What is the following limit?

$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}  \int_{-b}^b e^{-\frac{Nx^{2}}{2}}g(x)\,dx $

We are told to make a change of variables to make things easier.

Comment: Have you covered dominated/monotone convergence theorems?

Comment: What course did this question come from? Did you cover theorems like LDCT?

Comment: Yes this a graduate level real analysis course, focusing on measure theory and Lp spaces. Indeed, we have covered LDCT, which now I realize is a very helpful hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. If $f_N(x) = e^{-Nx^2/2} g(x)$, since $g$ is bounded on $[-b,b]$, say by $M > 0$, then $|f_N(x)| \leq M e^{-Nx^2/2} \leq M e^{-x^2/2}$ for all $N$ so that the sequence is uniformly integrable on $[-b,b]$. Furthermore, $f_N(x) \to 0$ almost everywhere. Therefore, by the LDCT, 
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}  \int_{-b}^b e^{-\frac{Nx^{2}}{2}}g(x)\,dx &= \left(\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\right)\left(\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-b}^b e^{-\frac{Nx^{2}}{2}}g(x)\,dx\right)\\
&= \left(\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\right)\left(\int_{-b}^b \lim_{N\to\infty}  e^{-\frac{Nx^{2}}{2}}g(x)\,dx\right) \\
&= 0 \cdot 0 = 0. 
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Does bounded convergence also apply here?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of terms, but what do you mean by bounded convergence?

Comment: Bounded convergence theorem is a special case of DCT that, if a function sequence on a set of finite measure is uniformly bounded and converges pointwise a.e., then we can draw the same conclusion as in DCT. This theorem can be proven without aid of the MCT or DCT, using the Egorov theorem.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. In that case, then yes, bounded convergence can be applied here.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to notice that, the sequence $ \frac{e^{-\frac{N x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{N}} $ converges uniformly to $0$ on the interval $[-b,b]$.